# Can RealmClass setter use method chaining?

Tags: android, realm

I wasn't able to find clear documentation on this for the Java SDK. I'm working with Android.

The example say to do something like

```
@RealmClass
public class User {
   @PrimaryKey
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

but can I instead have my setter return the class itself?

```
   public User setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
   }
```

This way I can do something like

```
User user = new User().setName("Bob");
```

instead of

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("Bob")
```

Is Realm going to process the setter properly?

Comment: Probably.  Why not just try it and see if you can store an object and query it.

Comment: Yes it can since 0.88.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a model class like the below is perfectly valid:

```
@RealmClass
public class User implements RealmModel {

   @PrimaryKey
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public User setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
   }
}
```